# split file by reading file and comparing line to a string - shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to write a shell script in order to read a file line by line and compare the line to a string and if that matches create file and start putting the lines read in that file.

Here is what i have written so far :

```
FILENAME=27_04_2015.txt
val=0
COMP=file_number_$val
while read line
do  
    line2=${line//[[:blank:]]/} 
    if [ "$line2" = "$COMP" ]
    then        
        val = val + 1   
        COMP=filenumer_$val                     
    fi
done < $FILENAME
```

In my FILENAME file, thefile_number_0 string is present but the if test doesn't return success.

Thank you for your help.

Edit 1: Is there a command which allows us to search for some characters in a string ? (like strncmp in C++)

Comment: `=` needs to be `==` inside `if` block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
FILENAME=27_04_2015.txt
val=0
COMP=file_number_$val
while read line
do  
    line2=${line//[[:blank:]]/} 
    if [ "$line2" == "$COMP" ]
    then        
        ((val++))   
        COMP=file_number_$val     
        echo $val               
    fi
done < $FILENAME
```

Comment: I did try this but it seems like it doesn't work either because i tried to print the value of val inside if then and it shows nothing.

Comment: It shows 1 for me, as I have put **file_number_0** inside the file. put `echo $val` after `COMP=file_number_$val ` and make sure your file has a new line at the end.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, then you should consider accepting it. There's a tick mark at the left of the answer for accepting.

Comment: I was about to mark the post resolved but i had another question which will surely allow me to do what i want. Is there a command which allows us to search for some characters in a string ? (like strncmp in C++)

Comment: You can use wildcard `*` to do that. Say, `string` is the string and the character is `r`. Then you can check that with the condition `"string" == *"r"*`